# postman get not passing parameters in short format

Tags: http, https, get

I am trying to send a get request with postman. If I pass parameters like this

```
  {{base_url}}/api/v1/views/PersonView?LastName=SomeLastName
```

It doesn't recognize them and I get the same response as for "{{base_url}}/api/v1/views/PersonView"

But if I pass parameters like this

```
  {{base_url}}/api/v1/views/PersonView?param[0][name]=LastName&param[0][op]=eq&param[0][value]=SomeLastName
```

then i get the correct answer. As far as I understand, both approaches are the same, only the format is different. What could be the problem with sending parameters as shown in the first example?

Comment: Thoes It depends on the api. Two your query params are not the same.

Comment: Could you add some details? What could be the difference for api and what can I google to go deeper?

Comment: I mean from your side, you can't do anything. What parameter or how parameter will be evaluated totally depends on Back-end code. You should follow the api document or ask BE dev about it. I can't help you on this issue.